# Excel: how to reference formula result from another sheet that uses all current sheet column values as arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Required:**

Use formula defined on sheet 1 to calculate output using every row of column from sheet 2 as input arguments **and** show calculation result on sheet 2 next to every formula input value.

**Given:**

Two sheets: `MYFORMULA` and `MYVALUES`.

`MYFORMULA` sheet contains a formula that multiplies input value by 2. Its cells are:

```
A1: 3
A2: =A1*2 (thus, 6)
```

`MYVALUES` sheet contains a column A with values 2,3,4:

```
A1: 2
A2: 3
A3: 4
```

**Question:**

How do I create a column B in `MYVALUES` sheet that feeds respective values of column A as argument to `MYFORMULA`.`A2` cell?

I expect every cell from `MYVALUES`.`A` column to be multiplied by two, so I'd have `MYVALUES`.`B` looking as:

```
B1: 4
B2: 6
B3: 8
```

Comment: You recreate the formula in column B.

Comment: No way to reuse what's on my formula sheet?

Comment: not without vba.  And that vba would need to be very robust and make assumptions.

Comment: and with VBA? In reality the formula is quite complex, I'd hate copy/pasting it to every row of MYVALUES

Comment: you would copy paste once and make the references relative then copy/drag the formula down.  It does not take long.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b?

Comment: If you have a complex formula that you want to reuse without VBA, you can use the name manager to give a name to a LAMBDA function. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67